# Graph-Tool GraphView Object

Tags: python, graph, graph-tool

I have a filtered graph generated using graph-tool's `GraphView()`.

```
g = gt.GraphView(g, vfilt= label_largest_component(g, directed=False))
```

The original graph `g` has 10,069 vertices while the resulting graph has 9,197. However, using the new (filtered) graph, when I list the in-degrees using `indeg = g.degree_property_map("in")`, the total number of elements in `list(indeg.a)` is still 10,069. This becomes problematic when plotting the new filtered graph with 9,197 nodes where the vertex sizes are set as a function of `indeg`, essentially because of the mismatched number of elements.

The code snippet looks like this

```
g = load_graph("ppnet.xml")
g = GraphView(g, vfilt=label_largest_component(g, directed=False))
indeg = g.degree_property_map("in")
indeg.a = np.sqrt(indeg.a) + 2
graph_draw(g, vertex_size = indeg, vertex_fill_color=indeg, pos = sfdp_layout(g),
    vcmap=plt.cm.gist_heat, output_size=(400, 400), output="gc.png")
```

which when run, gives the following `ValueError`

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10069,) (9197,)
```

What is the proper way to add the intended style for `GraphView` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. I first created a *copy* of the `GraphView` object and then purged the vertices of this *copy*. Note that instead of retaining the variable name `g`, I introduced a new variable `gc` for clarity.

```
g = load_graph("ppnet.xml")
gc = GraphView(g, vfilt=label_largest_component(g, directed=False)).copy()
gc.purge_vertices()
indeg = gc.degree_property_map("in")
indeg.a = np.sqrt(indeg.a)+2
graph_draw(gc, vertex_size = indeg, vertex_fill_color=indeg, pos = sfdp_layout(gc),
    vcmap=plt.cm.gist_heat, output_size=(400, 400), output="gc.png")
```

Comment: This is indeed a bug. I will fix it soon. A better work-around is to use "g = Graph(g, prune=True)" instead of the copy and purge.

Comment: FYI, this has already been fixed in graph-tool in recent versions.